# Google Chart: How to show difference between points

Tags: google-visualization

I want to show difference between point in Google Line Chart with respect to y-axis which are just numbers. Like hovering between two points. Any clue how to do it?

> **.**  Hover "difference" between points (at center of line of that points)  **.**

Or any other way to show difference

```
function drawBackgroundColor(graphData1) {
//alert(graphData1);
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Mimi Types');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});


  data.addRows(JSON.parse(graphData1));

  var options = {
      title: Charttitle,
    hAxis: {
      title: hAxisTitle,
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: yAxisTitle,
    },
    backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9',
    pointSize: 5,
   // visibleInLegend: false

    tooltip: { textStyle: { fontSize: 12 }, isHtml: true }


  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);


}
```

Comment: @WhiteHat i updated the post. You can see the code now

Comment: if you want a tooltip to show when you hover _between_ two points, then a point will have to exist at that location. similar to the tooltip column, you could use a style column to set the point size to zero for the hover points

Comment: noticed this somewhat, [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36271023/5090771)...